# A @OneToMany relationship in JPA and IS NOT EMPTY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I need to select all articles who do have work flow tasks associated with them.
I tried to use the following JPA query (icm with the Play! Framework, JPA, Hibernate):

```
 List<Article> list = find("site.app=? AND workflowSteps IS NOT EMPTY ORDER BY pubDate DESC", app).fetch();
```

But this gives the fool wing error:

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: workflowStep is not mapped [from models.Article where site.app=? AND workflowSteps IS NOT EMPTY ORDER BY pubDate DESC]
```

The relevant code for the entities are:

```
@Entity
public class Article extends TemporalModel {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<WorkflowStep> workflowSteps;
}

@Entity
public class WorkflowStep extends TemporalModel {

    public WorkflowStepType type;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="article")
    public Article article;
}
```

Is this possible this way, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is just a complete mystery to me. It is complaining about a 'workflowStep' not being mapped, with a lower-case W. If there was an entity mapping problem I'd expect it to complain about WorkflowStep with a capital W. At this point I have no clue as to what JPA actually has a problem with; I'm suspecting its not in what you posted.

Comment: i figured it out I think. It has to do with the short query somehow, as if I write it out it seems to work as expected, but need to do a bit more testing

Answer (score 1):

You must map your entities to their respective tables and add `@Table` annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTICLE")
public class Article extends ....

.....

@Entity
@Table(name="WORKFLOW_STEP")
public class WorkflowStep extends ....
```

Answer (score 0):

QuerySyntaxException:It seems your query class name is not correct.
**In the HQL , you should use the java class name and property name of the mapped @Entity instead of the actual table name.**